# Is there a shorter code for this?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$list = array( 'title', 'cat' );

$insert = array();
foreach( $list as $k ):
     $insert[$k] = $_POST[$k];
endforeach;
```

Simple question. Wondering if there's a function for this

Comment: Somewhere a database is screaming in terror...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$insert = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip(array('title', 'cat')));
```